# Removing duplicates in lists of objects keeping the max and the order

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dict and i want to remove all objects with an equal x value keeping the y max value and the list order. I made the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pprint import pprint
import operator

lst = [{'x': 207, 'y': 40}, {'x': 207, 'y': 45}, {'x': 254, 'y': 62}, {'x': 260, 'y': 26}, {'x': 351, 'y': 71}, {'x': 351, 'y': 5},  {'x': 351, 'y': 15},  {'x': 391, 'y': 24},  {'x': 391, 'y': 48}]

pprint(lst)
[{'x': 207, 'y': 40},
 {'x': 207, 'y': 45},
 {'x': 254, 'y': 62},
 {'x': 260, 'y': 26},
 {'x': 351, 'y': 71},
 {'x': 351, 'y': 5},
 {'x': 351, 'y': 15},
 {'x': 391, 'y': 24},
 {'x': 391, 'y': 48}]

copy = []
[
    copy.append(max(
        (point2 for point2 in lst if point["x"] == point2["x"]),
        key=operator.itemgetter('y'))
    )
    for point in lst
        if next(
            (cPoint for cPoint in copy if cPoint['x'] == point['x']),
            None) == None
]

pprint(copy)
[{'x': 207, 'y': 45},
 {'x': 254, 'y': 62},
 {'x': 260, 'y': 26},
 {'x': 351, 'y': 71},
 {'x': 391, 'y': 48}]
```

I'm just asking if there is a more elegant (and Pythonic) way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your list comprehension use is... circumspect. You are using a list comprehension *side effect* to build a list. Remove `copy = []` and just use `copy = [max(...) ...]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought so, too, but he is making a reference to `copy` inside that list comprehension. Agreed, though, that using a list-comprehension for side-effects is bad.

Comment: @tobias_k: ah, yes, which illustrates the point nicely. List comprehensions should *only* be used to build an actual list. If you cannot use a list comprehension here because you are referencing the list-built-so-far all the time, then *just use a `for` loop*. The OP is confusing the hell out of people reading the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [tobias_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28497661/1071311), here is one in a more functional style. First, we group all elements of `lst` by their `x` value, then, for each group, we get the one with the largest `y`. Afterwards, we can just go though all elements of `lst` and check if it's inside the list of maxima. If it is, put it into `copy`:

```
import itertools

getx, gety = lambda a: a['x'], lambda a: a['y'] # or use operator.itemgetter
groups = itertools.groupby(sorted(lst, key=getx), key=getx)
m = [max(b, key=gety) for a,b in groups]
copy = [l for l in lst if l in m]
```

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I didn't know itertools.groupby.

Answer (score 2):

How about this: First create a dictionary holding the maximum `y` value for each `x`, then keep those values from the list that have that highest `y` value for their respective `x`.

```
maxima = {}
for d in lst:
    x, y = d["x"], d["y"]
    if x not in maxima or y > maxima[x]:
        maxima[x] = y
copy = [d for d in lst if d["y"] == maxima[d["x"]]]
```